# FormData, XMLHttpRequest with blob image on iOS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, mobile-safari

I'm trying to convert pasted images (blobs) in `contentEditable` elements to 'proper' images by uploading them.

My code for getting the images and uploading them.

```
function convertimages(article)
{
  images = article.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].src.startsWith('blob:')){

      formData = new FormData();

      fetch(images[i].src)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.blob()
        })
        .then(function(blob) {
          formData.append("image", blob );
        });

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST","image.php",false);

      xmlhttp.send(formData);
      images[i].src = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

And my code for handling the upload:

```
//create unique ID for filename
$id = uniqid();
$dest = './images/kip'.$id;

if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $dest )){
  echo $dest;
} else {
  echo "error.jpg";
}
```

But when inspecting `$_FILES`, it is an empty array.

Comment: Welcome @beiert! What you've provided here doesn't actually show us where `$_FILES` is set, and is missing enough that we can't tell what's going wrong. I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question so we can debug what's going on.

Comment: $_FILES is set by the php runtime, containing: "An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST method uploads section. "

Comment: I've since triaged it to POSTing before the promise (fetch) has completed executing, with an empty formData

Answer (score 0):

Promises..Promises

```
async function convertimages(article)
{
  images = article.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if(images[i].src.startsWith('blob:')){

      formData = new FormData();

      await fetch(images[i].src)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.blob()
        })
        .then(function(blob) {
          formData.append("image", blob );
        }).then(function(){
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.open("POST","image.php",false);
          xmlhttp.send(formData);
          images[i].src = xmlhttp.responseText;
    });
    }
  }
}
```

My first experience with them

Comment: This kind of works but I feel I'm butchering the whole async/stay off the main thread mantra